# Microsoft Graph Planner Create new Task .NET

Tags: c#, .net, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create an Application which automatically creates a Task in Microsoft Graph (Microsoft App -> "Planner") in .NET (C#).

I already got the Authentification done but im not sure how to create a new Task or update a existing Task because I don't understand the Syntax.

[image: Screenshot of my Code]

The Problem is that there are no examples for Plans in Graph for .Net only stuff for Web Apps and so on.
[Link to api-reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_tasks)

Im using the latest Microsoft Graph .Net Library
[found here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph)

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of your code.

Comment: Okay. Iam really sorry. I thought its easier to read :P

Comment: Please provide your source code instead.

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern of request formulation in the .NET SDK is that it parallels the REST API hierarchy ('planner' lives under the root, and has a child called 'tasks'), at the end of which you build the request by invoking `Request()`, followed by the action you want to take (`.AddAsync`, `.GetAsync`).

In this case, you first want to create a `PlannerTask` object that represents the task you want to create.

```
PlannerTask myTask = new PlannerTask();
myTask.PlanId = id; //a valid planner id
myTask.Title = "New task title";
PlannerTask createdTask = await graphClient.Planner.Tasks.Request().AddAsync(myTask);
```

Comment: Yes Thanks I also got it yesterday. ;)